# Why all rows of the table are not produced in the output?

Tags: tables, longtable, output

Full output

[image]

After zooming the last part of page 2nd

[image]

I put more than 60 rows in the source but the output pdf shows only 60. Why?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{NikoshLightBAN}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0.1cm,right=0.1cm,top=0.1cm,bottom=0.1cm]{geometry}
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\noindent
%\nopagebreak[0]
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.13cm}|p{1.3cm}|p{1cm}|p{2.3cm}|p{2.3cm}|p{1.3cm}|p{2.3cm}|p{1.3cm}|p{2.3cm}|p{2.3cm}|}
\hline
\tiny{ক্রমিক নং} & ডিপার্টমেন্ট &  বর্ষ & PL শুরুর তারিখ & PL শেষের তারিখ & মোট PL (দিন) & পরীক্ষা শেষের তারিখ & ল্যাবের আগে বন্ধ (দিন) & ল্যাব শুরুর তারিখ & ল্যাব শেষের তারিখ\\
\rownumber & Chemistry & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Chemistry & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Chemistry & 3rd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Chemistry & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Chemistry & MS &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Chemistry & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Physics & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Physics & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Physics & 3nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Physics & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Physics & MS &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Math & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Math & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Math & 3rd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Math & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Math & MS &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Applied Math & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Applied Math & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Applied Math & 3rd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Applied Math & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Applied Math & MS &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Botatny & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Botatny & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Botatny & 3rd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Botatny & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Botatny & MS &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Pharmacy & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Pharmacy & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Physicsn & 3rd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Pharmacy & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Pharmacy & MS &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & EEE & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & EEE & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & EEE & 3rd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & EEE & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & EEE & MS &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & CSE & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & CSE & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & CSE & 3rd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & CSE & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & CSE & MS &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & ISRT & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & ISRT & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & ISRT & 3rd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & ISRT & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & ISRT & MS &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Statistics & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Statistics & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Statistics & 3rd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Statistics & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Statistics & MS &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Nuclear & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Nuclear & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Nuclear & 3rd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Nuclear & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Nuclear & MS &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Robotics & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Robotics & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Robotics & 3rd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Robotics & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Robotics & MS &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Oceanography & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Oceanography & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Oceanography & 3rd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Oceanography & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Oceanography & MS &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Zeology & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Zeology & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Zeology & 3rd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Zeology & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Zeology & MS &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Zoology & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Zoology & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Zoology & 3rd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Zoology & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Zoology & MS &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Fisheries & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Fisheries & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Fisheries & 3rd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Fisheries & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & Fisheries & MS &&&&&&&\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\vspace*{1cm}
নিচের নমুনা অনুসারে লিখলে ভাল হয়\\ 

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.13cm}|p{5.6cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{2cm}|p{1cm}|p{1.4cm}|p{5.6cm}|}
\hline
{\tiny  ক্রমিক} নং &  নাম &  রুম নং &  ডিপার্টমেন্ট &  বর্ষ & পূর্বে লাগানো সময় & জিম্মাদার সাথীর নাম\\
\hline
01 & ভাই মোঃ আব্দুল্লাহ & ১৬১০  & EEE & ২য় & ১ চিল্লা & ভাই মোঃ আরাফাত\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Might it just be that the table is too long and you may have to switch to `longtable`?

Comment: @marmot Why do some rows not go to next page?

Comment: A single tabular does not allow page breaks. If it is too long, the excess rows will just get "eaten". Please consider using `longtable`, which is made for this, and is really good.

Comment: There is no problem with the second tabular. The problem is that the first one is too long. Please use longtable. Unfortunately, I use a very old editor, and you are using special characters, so I cannot provide you an example.

Comment: @marmot I am trying?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem, which was that the table was too long for a `tabular` environment, has been solved in the comments.

Comment: Off-topic: For the very first column, don't use `p{0.13cm}`. Instead, just use the `r` column type. Also, you may want to change all instances of `Botatny` to `Botany`...

Comment: @Mico would you please describe why `r` is better than `p{0.13cm}`

Comment: @alhelal - The `r` column type will make LaTeX use the minimally required amount of space. In contrast, the `p` column type does not. Moreover, there's no need to allow for line breaks in first column.

Comment: @Mico ok, but now it takes space greater than `0.13cm`

Comment: @alhelal -- If the numbers in column 1 take up more than 1.3mm in horizontal space, the only sensible conclusion is that it's not correct to allocate only 1.3mm of space.